# Regex NotBlank and doesnt contains <

Tags: java, regex

I try to create a regex for a String which is NotBlank and cannot contain "<".
My question is what Im doing wrong thank you.

```
"(\\A(?!\\s*\\Z))|([^<]+)"
```

Edit
Maybe this way how to combine this regex

```
^[^<]+$
```

with this regex

```
\\A(?!\\s*\\Z).+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regex, you can use

```java
\A(?!\s+\z)[^<]+\z
(?U)\A(?!\s+\z)[^<]+\z
```

The `(?U)` is only necessary when you expect any Unicode chars in the input.

In Java, when used with `matches`, the anchors on both ends are implicit:

```java
text.matches("(?U)(?!\\s+\\z)[^<]+")
```

The regex in `matches` is executed once and requires the full string match. Here, it matches

- `\A`  - (implicit in `matches`) - start of string
- `(?U)` - `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` option enabled so that `\s` could match any Unicode whitespaces
- `(?!\\s+\\z)` - until the very end of string, there should be no one or more whitespaces
- `[^<]+` - one or more chars other than `<`
- `\z` - (implicit in `matches`) - end of string.

See the [Java test](https://ideone.com/kKsy21):

```java
String texts[]  = {"Abc <<", "     ", "", "abc 123"};
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?U)(?!\\s+\\z)[^<]+");
for(String text : texts)
{
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    System.out.println("'" + text + "' => " + m.matches());
}
```

Output:

```java
'Abc <<' => false
'     ' => false
'' => false
'abc 123' => true
```

See an [online regex test](https://regex101.com/r/bYsUyI/1/)  (modified to fit the single multiline string demo environment so as not to cross over line boundaries.)

Comment: @nusia `null` is not a *String* type. Regex only operates on *String*s. No regex in any language detects `null`. There is only one way to do that: cast/coalesce `null` value to a string. And if you manage to do that, you will need to add `null` to the above  regex as ``(?!(?:\\s+|null)\\z)``.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this regex:

```
[^<\s]+
```

Any char that is not "<", for 1 or more times.

Here is the example to test it: https://regex101.com/r/9ptt15/2

However, you can try to solve it without a regular expression:

```
boolean isValid = s != null && !s.isEmpty() && s.indexOf(" ") == -1 && s.indexOf("<") == -1;
```